# How to do 3 jQuery callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, callback

I want to have three functions to be performed in order. First, enlarge a object, then rotate 360 degrees, last resize to the size it was before enlargement. I can do the first and second, but I don't know how to do the last.

How can I accomplish this using jQuery callbacks? Can anyone give me a structure to work from? I am so new to jQuery.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#abc').click(function () {
                    $(this).animate({               
                        width: '+=90px',
                        height: '+=90px',
                        fontSize: '300%'
                    }, function(){
                        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
                    });             
                   // add function -- resize to normal
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .rotate {       
                transition: all 0.7s;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(6.28rad);
                -ms-transform: rotate(6.28rad);
                transform: rotate(6.28rad); 
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>  
        <div id="abc" style="border:1px solid;width:90px;">HTML / CSS</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That in itself works, right?

Comment: Seems to work, except the `;` after 120% and the missing jQuery lib in the snippet... What is your question from this?

Comment: You know we can still see what was in your previous edit right? You had used the callback correctly to perform the 3 steps... So clarify what was wrong with it or anything else... Your question is unclear.

Comment: I mean when I try to add the last one in the callback, the whole function doesn't work. So I put the comment "add function -- resize to normal" in my code and ask for help

Comment: Are you wanting it to work like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96h4rjpp/)?

Comment: *«the whole function doesn't work»* -- I told you above... About the `;` right after 120% (in your 1st edit). That is a synxtax error bugging all the function.

Comment: John S: Yes, I want this, but your demo is same as my try that after diminishing, the border doesn't resize to normal.

Comment: It works good for me using Firefox and IE, but in Chrome the border shrinks to a single pixel. Works better when using absolute values: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96h4rjpp/1/)

Comment: Final question, if i want to change background-color (toggle) after all animation finished, how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual link I have created for you https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/t83xmj8h/. I have modified your code :)

I used `CSS keyframes` for animating the div element and added `setTimeout` function to the jquery, I have estimated the time that works fine :)

Comment: It doesn't work on second click... But I think you're close.

Comment: This is what I want, thanks for your help. However, it seems not work if I click it again, how to solve this?

Comment: I change addClass to toggleClass, but it looks strange.

Comment: I have modified my code and used css animation only. It works fine!

Comment: Just for you to know, the prefixes on `transform` are not needed. [See here](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform). +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to suggest an full CSS animation for that "complex" animation, using [`@keyFrames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

And a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to remove the animation class after.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // Click handler
  $('#abc').click(function() {

    // CSS Animation!
    $(this).addClass("twist");
    
    // Remove the class after the animation...
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#abc').removeClass("twist");
    },3000);  // Same delay as the animation time ( 3s )
  });
});
```

```css
#abc{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.twist{
  animation-name: bigtwist;
  animation-duration:3s;
}

@keyFrames bigtwist{
  0%{
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0rad);
  }
  30%{
    transform: scale(3) translate(50%, 50%) rotate(0rad);
  }
  70%{
    transform: scale(3) translate(50%, 50%) rotate(6.28rad);
  }
  99.9%{
    transform: scale(1) translate(0%, 0%) rotate(6.28rad);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1) translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0rad);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>  
  <div id="abc">HTML / CSS</div>
</body>
```